# Chart.JS using Angular.JS on JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js, cdn, jsfiddle

I'm trying to create a tested graph mimicking this chart from this [documentation](https://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/).

[image]

In my JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/2pcmubwq/)

I tried adding all the links needed in the resources :

- https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js
- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js
- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-chart.js/0.10.2/angular-chart.js

## HTML

```
<canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar"
  chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels"> chart-series="series"
</canvas>
```

## JS

```
angular.module("app", ["chart.js"]).controller("BarCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.labels = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
  $scope.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];

  $scope.data = [
    [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
    [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
  ];
});
```

## Result

I see no errors in the console, but this white screen.

What did I do wrong to make my graph didn't render?

[image]

Comment: In the future use a linter or IDE that can spot errors for you. The HTML is badly formed.

Comment: Ok. Will do. I was playing with js fiddle forgot to test it locally. I would have caught that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every angularJs app have to be mounted in the document using those directives: `ng-app` `ng-controller`
Your fiddle fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/nmwypgdq/9/

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="BarCtrl">
  <canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series"></canvas>
</div>
```

`$scope` object passed by controller callback is available in your template. You can reference its properties and methods in the template. Thus `chart-data="data"` binds HTML element property `chart-data` with `$scope.data` defined in the controller callback. `chart-labels` is bound with `$scope.labels` and so on...